# Make Highcharts Bar Charts With Date Picker

Tags: highcharts

I want to make a chart  like this [Highchart][1] to show my current data 
for a **2g,3g,sd ,hd** data for a channel ex star plus

with  a **date picker** such that it works with  the selected date range , but i don't know how to do so if any one can give me idea how to do that please provide

i have tried which has possible way to show my data.
[fiddle][1]
but i want to have to data in which it has date range with the bar

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/p2MF6/embedded/result/
```

Comment: Please take a [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The rangeselector is available only in the highstock, so in the highcharts you need to prepare html inputs, attach datepicker and call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) event to have a custom range.

Comment: can u please tell how can i do this ,i have added an explict date picker but m not getting how to do that

Comment: Have you an example which has a datepicker and let me know which part of your chart doenst work ?

Comment: i have done it using highcharts but dnt know how cn i do this with stacked bar

Comment: How about my soltuion, have you tried to add inputs, attach datepicker and call setExtremes on the chart?